# How to fetch apk icon from its path in flutter Android

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I have an app which shows list of all the apps from internal storage and their details like if I have  firefox app in my internal storage saved as firefox.apk, then I want to show all the details of the apk named firefox.apk like its icon, package name and also the Application name itself as it can be `Firefox` or `Firefox Beta` or even `Firefox Nightly`.

I have the list of apps with their path, but I only want a function which can return app info like its icon, name and package name, by specifying its path using kotlin, Java or dart.

Comment: I greatly doubt that there is a function in Dart code that allows you to do this. The location of the app's icon in an Android app is, by definition, Android-specific, so there's little point in the Flutter development team providing a Dart way to retrieve it. You will have to use method channels to native code in order to get that path (or see if there's an existing package that does this for you).

Comment: dont really understand what do you mean ??

Comment: @JanviPatel I have reframed the question, you can check it out now.

Comment: @Abion47 I have found several packages but they only retrieve Installed apps info but not from a Path, like device_apps, etc..  It is POSSIBLE in android but I am not aware of how to do it. Looks like I have to reverse engineer the apps and dig into their source to find that.

Comment: Why do you need to do it this way at all? Why not just pull the icon out and turn it into an asset?

Comment: @Abion47 Yeah but How to do that, how to pull an icon from an unknown apk and convert it into assets, I want all the apps from Users device listed with their icons and not some static icons.

Comment: So when you say you want to pull icons from an app apk on the user's phone, do you mean the apps that are installed on that phone or actual apk files that live on the phone's file structure somewhere?

Comment: @Abion47 the second case, I have already done the first case by using device_apps plugin.

Comment: Well that you can just read the APK file itself. I'd suggest taking a look at the APK file format, which suggests it's a glorified archive (zip, perhaps), in which case you can use an archive package to open it up all load the icon from the archive assets.